# Core plot objective-c, I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic, Labels are coming on y-axis with a delay, How to stop this delaying?

Tags: core-plot

Core plot objective-c, I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic, Labels are coming on y-axis with a delay, How to solve this problem?

Comment: I am using coreplot 0.9 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed after the 0.9 release. See [the Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=363) for details.

You can either pull the latest code with Mercurial or wait for the next release.